# How can I find the formula of an exponential function given two sets of points?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The function g(x) has y-intercept 4 and goes through the point (2,4/49).
How can I use this to calculate the formula?

Comment: Let $y=g(x)=Ac^x$. Set $x=0$. We get $4=A$. Now use the given point to find $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd approach it like this. Let:
$$g(x)=\xi e^{\alpha x}$$

And we are given: $$\begin{cases}g(0)=4\\g(2)=\frac4{49}\end{cases}$$

So just plug it in:

$$g(0)=4=\xi e^0\Rightarrow \xi=4\\g(2)=\frac4{49}=4e^{2\alpha}\Rightarrow \alpha = -\frac12\ln49$$

And so you have:

$$\require{cancel}g(x)=4e^{-\frac12 \ln (49)x}=4\left(\cancelto{49}{e^{\ln 49}}\right)^{-\frac12x}=4\left(49^{-\frac12x}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much this helped a lot! I really appreciate it